# What will be the power if I add two laser with different wavelength at same power?

Tags: optics, power, photonics

I am trying to combine two lasers at 960nm and 1310nm wavelengths respectively with same power 150mW by using four wave mixing. I am planning to use a 3dB coupler for adding. I just want to know will I get 300mW at the output power or it will be remaining 150mW per wavelength?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the 3dB coupler will eat half of the power of *each* source, that is you will have 75mW/laser, the output sum of hte two sources will be 75+75=150mW.

Comment: You need to start with the efficiency of your 4-wave mixer.   Then you need to specify at which wavelength you want to determine the output power.   As you know, total energy is conserved, but the mixer may well dump some input into thermal.